# YT_DL downloading wrong video with ytsearch:{url}

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

## Tried

I tested how I best get the information of a video/if my code works and used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBtDx6ClkwY) link for it.
My code looks like this:

```py
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': "P:/DscMusic/testfile.wav",
    'noplaylist': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'wav',
        'preferredquality': '192', }]
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    dllink = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBtDx6ClkwY", download=False)['entries'][0]
    video_url = dllink['webpage_url']
    title = dllink['title']
    print(video_url, title)

print("Done")
```

## Problem

The Problem I got here now is that it always downloads the wrong video (some Russian Boxing Sports Video or whatever).
I also tried switching the link which just caused it downloading an other kind of this video.

## Output

```
[download] Downloading playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBtDx6ClkwY
[youtube:search] query "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBtDx6ClkwY": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBtDx6ClkwY: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] T_cfE1jBVzY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video T_cfE1jBVzY because of --no-playlist
[download] Finished downloading playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBtDx6ClkwY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_cfE1jBVzY Бодров VS Асрор. Бой за пояс. Отборы. Второй сезон. Киевстонер - ведущий
Done
```

## Thoughts

This works perfectly if I enter the title of the video and not the link. But as if I search on YT with Links it instantly shows the right result it should this should theoretically also work.

So anyone knows what I have done wrong or why this "doesn't" work?

Comment: Remove the `ytsearch:` bit if you want to download by URL alone?

Comment: But I want to be able to get it either by title or by URL so this wouldn't work

Comment: Then use e.g. a regular expression to figure out whether the input is an URL and if so, don't prepend `ytsearch:`.

Comment: So then I would just have to enter the URL instead of ytsearch:URL right?